# Why is my LCD 16*2 is not displaying any characters, although all the wiring is correct?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, pins, lcd

Recently I have linked up a typical 16*2 LCD (Liquid Crystal Display) display to my Arduino Uno and have linked all the pins up.

Here is my connection:(LCD pin first)

1=GND, 2=+5v, 4=11, 6=12, 11=5, 12=4, 12=3, 14=2, 15=backlight positive, 16=backlight negative

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

This is the code that is the default for the LCD, I didn't write it.

So I have done all this and when I turn it on the screen is blank and nothing is happening. Could anyone explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: What is connected to LCD pin 3? It is the contrast V0 and need to be connected with a 10 Kohm potentiometer. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld

Comment: I found connecting the LCD v0 (pin 3) to a 1k resistor to ground worked and provides a fairly viewable contrast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this tutorial on [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-11-lcd-displays-1). It will walk you through setting it up. In the tutorial they change the pins, which I believe is the issue here. Here is a snippet.

[image: Fritzing Diagram]

And change your pins:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
```

Answer (score 8):

Recently I also faced similar problem, with connection as:

1=GND, 2=+5v, 4=11, 6=12, 11=5, 12=4, 12=3, 14=2, 15=backlight positive, 16=backlight negative

Solution: I just **connected VEE (pin 3) of LCD to Ground (GND)** without use of potentiometer as it worked.

Comment: This will get you by in a pinch but at some viewing angles the LCD is hard to read.

Comment: If you don't need to constantly adjust the LED backlight brightness you can use a fixed resistor in place of the potentiometer.

Comment: This solution also worked for me. Just connect the ground with VEE(pin3) and showing display

Comment: worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

What is connected to LCD pin 3? Pin 3 is the contrast V0 and needs to be connected with a 10 KOhm potentiometer.

Some LCD's need a negative contrast voltage, check the datasheet of the display.

If the contrast voltage is not correct the display will stay blank. 
I came across the same problem until i saw the negative voltage must be applied :-)