# 16 X 2 LCD display blank with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, display, wires

So I am following [this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld) to make my arduino display hello world and `millis()`, I got it to work for a minute, but then it stopped updating the milliseconds, and when I pushed the reset button it went blank. since then, It has been blank but I have double, triple, and qaudruple checked checked my wiring, and it is flawless. I tried it with both of my 16 segment displays, but to no avail. I have redone the wiring, but it is still blank. Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

I followed this diagram [image: Fritzing diagram]
this is my code:

```cpp
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7); 

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

This is the result (the screen is lit up, but there is no text even when turning the potentiometer)
[image: Picture of the Arduino connected to the LCD display]

Comment: i'm having trouble scrolling down in your code listing .....  lol .... please list the text of the complete sketch .....remove the picture of the code

Comment: that is not a 16 segment display .... this is http://www.embeddedadventures.com/images/uploaded_images/DSP_16S04H_2_600.jpg

Comment: Please do not post images of code, paste the code itself, select it all and then press `{}` to properly format it. Also this display is 16x2 character one, not a segment one.

Comment: ok, I didn't have it formatted right, my code is in text now

Comment: I have no idea what I did, i added a serial println to see if for some reason the program wasn't getting into the loop, and it started working :) _EDIT: then I removed the println and it is still working... I guess it was a problem with the compiler or something... but I also checked the code so many times, and it was perfect_

Comment: Sorry for all the notifs, I fixed my code, and thanks for informing me that the display isn't a 16 segment display. Do any of you have an idea as to what may have been wrong?

Comment: I suspect that you wiggled a loose Dupont wire back to it's place. They're quite flimsy. In addition to that, please post your best theory as the answer and click on the check mark button to mark it as the correct answer, adding `(SOLVED)` to the title is not how Arduino SE works.

Comment: Alright, I will do

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer for two days, but I will check it then.

Comment: `Do any of you have an idea as to what may have been wrong?`  ..... perhaps the upload was failing and you did not see the error messages for some reason .... so you were re-running the same sketch over and over

Comment: I rewrote the sketch twice, I think it had to do with hardware, if you look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that I wasn't providing enough power to the arduino, and or had the potentiometer set to the wrong point. according to [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29179/lcd-16x2-blank-display), you shouldn't run the arduino and display off of USB, because it may not actually be providing 5 volts. So I plugged it into the wall using a DC adapter. It now works.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept your own answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: It won't let me accept it until tomorrow